# How to disable a tooltip for a specific dataset in ChartJS

Tags: javascript, jquery, chart.js

I displaying a chart where two types are included. Now I want to hide the toolbar for one dataset. I saw some discussion like this on [GitHub](https://github.com/chartjs/Chart.js/issues/1889), but this doesn't bring me further.

Here is an example of my Chart:

```js
Chart.defaults.global.legend.display = false;
var ctx = document.getElementById("chart").getContext("2d");
var data = {
  labels: ["Januar","Februar","März","April","Mai","Juni","Juli","August","September","Oktober","November","Dezember"],
  datasets: [
     {
       label: "Test",
       type: 'bar',
       backgroundColor: "#F29220",
       borderColor: "#F29220",
       data: [4,1,1,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,1]
     },
     {
       label: "Test2",
       type: 'bar',
       backgroundColor: "#F29220",
       borderColor: "#F29220",
       data: [4,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0]
     },
     {
       label: "",
       type: 'line',
       fillColor: "rgba(220,220,220,0)",
       pointColor: "rgba(220,220,220,0)",
       borderColor: "#FF0000",
       tooltip: false,
       data: [100, 100, 100, 100, 100, 100, 100, 100, 100, 100, 100, 100]
     }]
  };
  var myBarChart = new Chart(ctx, {
    type: 'bar',
    data: data,
    options: {
       scales: {
          xAxes: [{
             stacked: true,
             ticks: {
                fontColor: '#000',
             }
          }],
          yAxes: [{
             stacked: true,
             ticks: {
                beginAtZero: true,
                fontColor: '#000',
                callback: function(label, index, labels) {
                   return label + '%';
                }
             },
          }]
       },
       elements: {
          point:{
             radius: 0
          }
       },
       tooltips: {
          enabled: true,
          mode: 'single',
          callbacks: {
             label: function(tooltipItems, data) {
                 return data.datasets[tooltipItems.datasetIndex].label + ': ' + tooltipItems.yLabel + ' %';
          }
       }
    }
 }
 });
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/Chart.js/2.5.0/Chart.min.js"></script>
<canvas id="chart" width="740" height="370"></canvas>
```

How can I hide the tooltip just for the line chart? As you can see in the code, I already tried to insert the attribute "tooltip", but this doesn't work.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

As you already concluded, there isn't a way to configure chart.js out of the box to only show tooltips of specific datasets.  However, you can use the [plugin interface](http://www.chartjs.org/docs/#advanced-usage-creating-plugins) to create a plugin that can provide this functionality.

Here is a plugin that I created for your scenario that let's you configure which datasets you want the tooltip to display for.

```
Chart.plugins.register({
  // need to manipulate tooltip visibility before its drawn (but after update)
  beforeDraw: function(chartInstance, easing) {
    // check and see if the plugin is active (its active if the option exists)
    if (chartInstance.config.options.tooltips.onlyShowForDatasetIndex) {
      // get the plugin configuration
      var tooltipsToDisplay = chartInstance.config.options.tooltips.onlyShowForDatasetIndex;

      // get the active tooltip (if there is one)
      var active = chartInstance.tooltip._active || [];

      // only manipulate the tooltip if its just about to be drawn
      if (active.length > 0) {
        // first check if the tooltip relates to a dataset index we don't want to show
        if (tooltipsToDisplay.indexOf(active[0]._datasetIndex) === -1) {
          // we don't want to show this tooltip so set it's opacity back to 0
          // which causes the tooltip draw method to do nothing
          chartInstance.tooltip._model.opacity = 0;
        }
      }
    }
  }
});
```

With the new plugin in place, you can now use a new property in the `tooltips` config called `onlyShowForDatasetIndex` that accepts an array of dataset indexes that the tooltip should display for.

```
tooltips: {
  enabled: true,
  mode: 'single',
  // new property from our plugin
  // configure with an array of datasetIndexes that the tooltip should display for
  // to get the datasetIndex, just use it's position in the dataset [] above in the data property
  onlyShowForDatasetIndex: [0, 1],
  callbacks: {
    label: function(tooltipItems, data) {
      return data.datasets[tooltipItems.datasetIndex].label + ': ' + tooltipItems.yLabel + ' %';
    }
  }
}
```

Where the index value maps to the position of the dataset in the `datasets` property.

Take a look at this [codepen](http://codepen.io/jordanwillis/pen/MpzgqQ) to see this in action.  Notice the tooltips only show on the bar charts but not the line (since we did not include this dataset in the new configuration property).

Comment: very nice and easy solution. Thank you !

Comment: actually it's working but I get error when building `The expected type comes from property 'tooltips' which is declared here on type 'ChartOptions'` I have place it inside tooltip options

Answer (score 42):

There is now [a way to configure charjs to do this](https://github.com/chartjs/Chart.js/issues/1889#issuecomment-304695797); use the filter property:

```
tooltips: {
    filter: function (tooltipItem) {
        return tooltipItem.datasetIndex === 0;
    }
}
```

Comment: This is exactly what I need but not on a dataset level... I only need it on a specific data point level. For example on a donut where everything is the same dataset index of 0, but I need to only remove the tooltip from one of the datasets.

Comment: If only worked for me if I put the filters before the 'label' and 'title' callbacks. When I put the filter after the other callbacks, it doesn't work. Probably a bug.

Comment: In this example tooltips are displayed for data set index = 0. I have i.e. 5 datasets and need to hide tootip only on one of them. How do I do that?

Comment: This is the most current & relevant answer thanks @Florian Moser

Comment: @WojciechJakubas I want to show tooltips just for the last dataset, so changed to ``return tooltipItem.datasetIndex < (myChart.data.datasets.length - 1)`` worked for me.

Comment: Thanks for showing me filters! I was able to selectively hide specific labels while in `tooltips: {mode: 'index'}` by adding a `hideLabelFromTooltip` param for each dataset item and doing `!OPTIONS.data.datasets[tooltipItem.datasetIndex].hideLabelFromTooltip;` in the filter where OPTIONS is the config object.

Comment: In v3.7.0 if you're using callbacks your `title`, `label` and `footer` need to return empty string in order for filter to work.

Answer (score 10):

In the dataset declaration you can pass a parameter to each of the datasets that determines the hit radius (`pointHitRadius`) for the hover event.  If you set this to 0 it will prevent the tooltip from being launch.

```
noTipDataset = {
    label: "No Tooltips here",
    data: ...,
    pointHitRadius: 0,
    ...The rest of your data declaration here
}
```

PS: this works in chartJS V2.6 but I haven't tested versions further back

Comment: Actually this is a very clean solution for the specified issue.

Answer (score 3):

You can use this filter:

```
 tooltips: {
        filter: function (tooltipItem, data) {
             var datasetLabel = data.datasets[tooltipItem.datasetIndex];
             var datapointLabel = data.labels[tooltipItem.index];
             var datapointValue = data.datasets[tooltipItem.datasetIndex].data[tooltipItem.index];

              //you can also use tooltipItem.xlabel or ylabel to get datapoint label and value but here it depends on you chart orientation                

              if (datasetLabel=="production" && datapointLabel=="red" && datapointValue<30) {
                   return false;
              } else {
                   return true;
              }
        }
 }
```

Answer (score 3):

I used Florian Moser's solution above and could not get it to work. For me the solution was to put the filter code under 'options > plugins > tooltip' and *not* under 'options > tooltips'.

Note the difference in the path and in using the singular form of tooltip. So, working code for me in the chart options:

```
options: {
  plugins: {
    tooltip: {
      filter: function (tooltipItem) { 
        return tooltipItem.datasetIndex === 0
      }
    }
  }
}
```

I'm using Chart.js 4.2.1

Answer (score 1):

The only way I was able to get this to work (v3.6.1) was by setting both `pointRadius` and `pointHitRadius` to zero. This also removes the points from the graph for that dataset but in my case that was something I wanted as well.

```
datasets: [
  {
    data: [...],
    pointRadius: 0,
    pointHitRadius: 0,
  },
]
```

Comment: For this to work `intersect` needs to be set to `true`.