# ChartJS Tooltip displaying data from same dataset

Tags: chart.js

Currently working on a chart that displays upwards ~1000 datapoints at any given moment between 2-3 datasets.

The only thing is that each of the points has a different timestamp (x-value).

Our goal is that upon hovering on one data point, it also brings the closest data point from the other datasets as well. We were able to achieve that with:

```
options={{
    tooltips: {
        mode: 'x'
    }
}}
```

I understand that there is a default `pointHitRadius` and that seems to be the reason why multiple values of the same dataset are appearing in the same tooltip.

I made a simple test case: [TEST](https://jsfiddle.net/tomphan/3uxghz1p/8/)
I increased the `pointBorderRadius` and it seems to include 1-5 points at a time. 
**Is there a way to only include data from each dataset ONCE?**

The closest thing I found (before having to extend functionality), is that there is a [filter function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43118408/how-to-disable-a-tooltip-for-a-specific-dataset-in-chartjs) available.

However, from what I can see, it looks like it only returns one instance from each dataset. Which wouldn't be too helpful.

Anyone run into this issue?