# How to add custom tooltips to only one label in Chart.js?

Tags: javascript, chart.js

I have a bar chart with many datasets. I want to add a custom tooltip to just one of them, with some specific properties. In particular, this is my chart:

```
var grafoprocessi = new Chart(ctx2, {
// The type of chart we want to create
type: 'bar',

// The data for our dataset
data: {
    labels: ['Processi', 'Startup', 'OpenCoesione'],
    datasets: [{
        label: '2010',
        backgroundColor: 'rgb(255, 230, 230)',
        borderColor: 'rgb(255, 230, 230)',
        data: array2010
    },
    {label:'2011',
    backgroundColor: 'rgb(255, 204, 204)',
        borderColor: 'rgb(255, 204, 204)',
        data: array2011
    },
    {label:'2012',
    backgroundColor: 'rgb(255, 179, 179)',
        borderColor: 'rgb(255, 179, 179)',
        data: array2012
    },
    {label:'2013',
    backgroundColor: 'rgb(255, 102, 102)',
        borderColor: 'rgb(255, 102, 102)',
        data: array2013
    },
    {label:'2014',
    backgroundColor: 'rgb(255, 26, 26)',
        borderColor: 'rgb(255, 26, 26)',
        data: array2014
    },
    {label:'2015',
    backgroundColor: 'rgb(204, 0, 0)',
        borderColor: 'rgb(204, 0, 0)',
        data: array2015
    },
    {label:'2016',
    backgroundColor: 'rgb(153, 0, 0)',
        borderColor: 'rgb(153, 0, 0)',
        data: array2016
    },
    {label:'2017',
    backgroundColor: 'rgb(153, 0, 51)',
        borderColor: 'rgb(153, 0, 51)',
        data: array2017
    },
    {label:'2018',
    backgroundColor: 'rgb(230, 0, 76)',
        borderColor: 'rgb(230, 0, 76)',
        data: array2018
    },
    {label:'2019',
    backgroundColor: 'rgb(255, 26, 102)',
        borderColor: 'rgb(255, 26, 102)',
        data: array2019
    },
    {label:'2020',
    backgroundColor: 'rgb(255, 128, 170)',
        borderColor: 'rgb(255, 128, 170)',
        data: array2020
    }]
},

// Configuration options go here
options: {}
});
```

I want to add a custom tooltip to only one label, 'OpenCoesione', with data I have in an array. I don't know if there is a solution for this, as all I have already seen changes all tooltips. I want all tooltips to remain the same beside the bar of "OpenCoesione".

Answer (score 1):

A bit hacky solution but it seems to be working. [StackBlitz demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/js-ykrgee).

Looking at the other answers for similar questions (e.g. [How to diable a tooltip for a specific dataset](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43118408/how-to-disable-a-tooltip-for-a-specific-dataset-in-chartjs)) I could not find the way to **disable the tooltip dynamically** and use the custom tooltip instead.

The main idea is to leave the default tooltip enabled but change it to disabled in the `custom` tooltip function.

```js
  options: {
    responsive: true,
    tooltips: {
      enabled: true,
      custom: function (tooltipModel) {
        if (isCustomTooltipMode(tooltipModel, 'OpenCoesione')) {
          setDefaultTooltipEnabled(this, false);
        } else {
          setDefaultTooltipEnabled(this, true);
          return;
        }

        var tooltipEl = document.getElementById('chartjs-tooltip');
        // Hide if no tooltip
        if (tooltipModel.opacity === 0 && tooltipEl) {
          tooltipEl.style.opacity = 0;
          return;
        }

        // Create element on first render
        createCustomTooltip(this, tooltipEl, tooltipModel);
      }
    }
  }
```

```js
function isCustomTooltipMode(tooltipModel, labelName) {
  return tooltipModel.dataPoints == null || tooltipModel.dataPoints[0].xLabel === labelName;
}

/*
  the hacky way (could not find the better one)
*/
function setDefaultTooltipEnabled(chart, enabled) {
  chart._chart.tooltip._options.enabled = enabled;
}
```

In the `createCustomTooltip` function you can define how the tooltip for 'OpenCoesione' should look.

Chart.js docs that I've found useful:
[External custom tooltips](https://www.chartjs.org/docs/latest/configuration/tooltip.html#external-custom-tooltips), [Tooltip Model](https://www.chartjs.org/docs/latest/configuration/tooltip.html#tooltip-model), [Tooltip Item](https://www.chartjs.org/docs/latest/configuration/tooltip.html#tooltip-item-interface)